# mod_rewrite taking over all the links on the page

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, seo

I've used mod_rewrite to rewrite links on my site like so:

```
mysite.com/store/<store_id>/<store_name>/<page>
mysite.com/store.php?id=<store_id>&page=<page>
```

for example:

```
mysite.com/store/1313/johnny-walker-inc/13
mysite.com/store.php?id=1313&page=13
```

However, as a result, all my links that we're relationally placed now start at the end of the link, for example:

```
mysite.com/send_message.php
```

has become

```
mysite.com/store/1313/johnny-walker-inc/send_message.php
```

How can I fix this?

Here is my `mod_rewrite` code, in case I'm making a mistake with it:

```
RewriteRule ^store/([0-9]+)/[^/]+/([0-9]+)$ store.php?storeid=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make your links relative to the root, like so:

```
<a href="/send_message.php">link</a>
```

Note the slash before `send_message.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I personally only see one solution: Just make all your links absolute. It's not directly a problem with mod_rewrite, but the browsers way of interpreting these links. From their perspective you have a directory structure and they interpret the relative position accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions include a BASE href or just rewriting all the page elements that can be referenced by the imaginary context root you're showing the client.